# How to bind a property of a XAML view to a public variable in the code behind every time the property changes

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to take a property from a XAML control, specifically the TranslationX property, and store it in a public variable every time the value is changed.

I have tried using data binding by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and binding the TranslationX property to the public variable from my interface implementation, but had no luck

Essentially, I am needing the TranslationX property of a control to trigger function calls depending on the total displacement, ex. if the control is dragged to -200 in the X direction, it triggers function "Y". I cannot seem to access this translation value in a way that allows me to check if it is above or below a certain value.

I am very new to C# and Xamarin, so any advice is much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is my current ViewModel class:

```
public class ReceiptPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    double shift = 0;

    public double Shift
    {
        get => shift;
        set
        {
            if (shift == value)
                return;
            else
            {
                shift = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Shift));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

And here is my syntax for my Binding:

```
TranslationX="{Binding Shift}"
```

Comment: There's many ways to do this, can we treat this property as an application configuration?

Comment: I don't believe treating it as an application configuration is something that's needed. Its just a property from one view in one page. Not something that needs to be application wide.

Answer (score 0):

in your XAML

```
<SomeElement ... TranslationX="{Binding TransX}" ... />
```

in your ViewModel

```
double transX;

public double TransX {
  get { return transX; }
  set {
    transX = value;

    if (transX > somethresholdvalue) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I tried this. See my edit above for my code. It still does not update, and when I put a breakpoint in my set for my viewmodel, it never even gets triggered.

Comment: you might need to explicitly set two-way binding

Answer (score 0):

Follow the **[MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)**. 
Create a Base View Model with the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
Then your custom view model is going to inherit from that base class.

---

**BaseViewModel**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 

    bool isBusy = false;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

    string title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
```

Your custom class: 
**ReceiptPageViewModel**

```
public class ReceiptPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    double shift = 0;
    public double Shift
    {
        get { return shift; }
        set { SetProperty(ref shift, value); }
    }
}
```

And in your Xamarin Page set the `BindingContext` to the `ViewModel` 
(This is an example)

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    private ReceiptPageViewModel viewModel;
    public Page1()
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel = new ReceiptPageViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now you can set the property in the **XAML** view:

```
<SomeElement ... TranslationX="{Binding Shift}" ... />
```

Here you can view a full episode about [**MVVM Pattern**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZDQptTQZsk) with @JamesMontemagno as host.